# Faces will not Merge/join

Tags: mesh

I seem to be having a problem joining these 2 faces together on the letter A. This is not created using the text feature in blender, but an imported SVG file. I have limited dissolved the mesh to get to where I am now but I can't figure out how to merge these 2 together. Image attached. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You can't, you have a hole inside and in order to keep the hole you need to have edges linking inner vertices to outer vertices

Comment: thanks moonboots for clarifying. The only problem I have now is that if I want to bevel the edges or inset, it applies this to these additional edges too, which I don't want. Any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: you need to add edges instead of removing   ;)   I can try some screenshots

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated moonboots as I am not sure exactly what you mean. Jack

Answer (score 1):

Try to work with quads, it will help for the operations like inset, bevel or add edge loops, at the end if you need to smooth with a *Subdivision Surface*, just add some edge loops to sharp the edges:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Moonboots! Really appreciate you showing me!